# Not able to select an option on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, accelerate

I used the commad

```
!accelerate config
```

The cell keeps running and i am not able to chose from any of the options.
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWosj.png)

I tried writing the option, selecting the number of choice as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate default config (it will prompts the config location):

`!accelerate config default`

Then move to your *"home"* dir:

`!mv /root/.cache/huggingface/accelerate/default_config.yaml /content/`

Then edit manually and put back:

`!mv /content/default_config.yaml /root/.cache/huggingface/accelerate/`

And update (?) (Possibly this is not necessary)

`!accelerate config update`